# Blank screen on dual Monitor (Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: nvidia, 15.04

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04. I have two displays (laptop + Samsung). At the beginning, both displays worked without any problem (using the nouveau-driver). I've changed to the NVIDIA driver and then the external monitor turns on for 2 or 3 seconds, showing the correct screen-image & resolution, and then turns black. The monitor is listed as active. No mouse nor launch bar are displayed. It is just pitch black. I reverted to nouveau again, but the problem persisted.

I have a Lenovo T510 with Nvidia GT218M. The external monitor is a Samsung Syncmaster. The monitors are detected without problem.

I don't see big errors in the logs. I tried the NVIDIA settings, xconf, removing monitors.xml, etc. but nothing seems to help.

It feels like whatever I do and save, is overridden after a few seconds by another process turning this monitor off again.

Comment: Can you add the output of the command `xrandr` to your question? you can run this by going to the gnome-terminal program and typing it in and pressing enter.

Comment: Any log information ?

Comment: this might be an issue with the gnome after upgrade. try reconfiguring the same and check

Comment: Try these answers:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/557488/nvidia-dual-screens-second-monitor-blank?rq=1

Comment: This question has been asked a lot, here are some links to answers to try! https://askubuntu.com/questions/557488/nvidia-dual-screens-second-monitor-blank?rq=1 https://askubuntu.com/questions/623367/ubuntu-15-04-flashes-log-in-screen-then-black?rq=1 Please tell me if any of these(and which one) worked. Also, when will it turn on for 3 seconds, after you plug it in, or when you turn on your computer?

Comment: are you sure installed recommended nvidia driver from additional driver ? have you try with this ?
- sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
- reboot
- Open setting->display and Detect Displays

Comment: This might be fixed by using an HDMI cable coming off the Lenovo laptop and a DVI-AVG adapter to the back of the Syncmaster.