# Dual monitor won't work together (one screen blank)

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, kde

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 kde plasma 5 - Dell xps laptop - graphics card nvidia GeForce GT 550m.

My two monitors won't work together! When I set the laptop screen as principal monitor, the external monitor is just blank. I can see the cursor, I can drag windows, but this is all I can do. And vice versa, the same thing happen when I set the external monitor as principal display!

I have tried several drivers (nouveau, proprietary...), I've tried to change settings in kde monitor settings and nvidia x server, I even tried to speak gently to my computer

Can you help me please?

Comment: This question has been asked a lot, here are some links to answers to try! https://askubuntu.com/questions/557488/nvidia-dual-screens-second-monitor-blank?rq=1 https://askubuntu.com/questions/623367/ubuntu-15-04-flashes-log-in-screen-then-black Please tell me if any of these(and which one) worked. Also, does the other monitor ever show the correct screen for a couple seconds? As other users with the same problem can see the correct thing for 2-3 seconds before it turns blank.

Comment: I suspect the solution there is out of date?

Answer (score 0):

I have the Nvidia 540M and I also faced some problems with Nouveau driver, but I figured out a solution quite simply after hours and days of search, when Nvidia finally released there driver on Ubuntu.

- I suggest you to install the latest tested Nvidia Driver (346.96) by using the graphical interface (Drivers > Additional Drivers).
- Do not forget to reboot after a proper installation and ensure that you actually run this driver.
- Then, open NVIDIA X Server settings. On "Prime profiles" menu, check "Nvidia (Performance mode)".
- You can finally perform some checks while pluging in in your monitor. It should appear on the Server settings menu, and can be easily configured.

Comment: I already tried this, but I will give it a try again. I will also try Bumblebee, see if it solves my problems. thx